# How to style Microsoft PowerBI with different height depending on the tab selected?

Tags: reactjs, powerbi, powerbi-embedded

Currently, I am using PowerBIEmbed from power-bi-client-react and passing the styling class using cssClassName. However, the css is applying for all the tabs. How can I apply different height depending on the tab selected?

I have the following Report.js:

```
<PowerBIEmbed
   embedConfig={embedReportConfig}
   eventHandlers={eventHandlersMap}
   cssClassName="report-overview-container"
   getEmbeddedComponent={(embedObject) => {
     setReport(embedObject);
   }}
/>
```

and Report.css:

```
.report-overview-container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    height: 1280px;
 }
```

Is there a way to apply different heigh for each tab? something like the following:

```
cssClassName = {showTab1? "small-height" : "medium-height"}
```

Thanks a lot

Comment: You can try custom layout: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/javascript/api/overview/powerbi/custom-layout